# Ring theory, isomorphism proof.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R=\{(a,b)∈Z\times Z: a\equiv b \mod 2\}$.
I need to prove that $Z[x]/(x^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $R$.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried/thought so far, so we know what you are stuck on. Also, see this post for a tutorial on how to typeset math in your posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the map $\phi:\mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow R $,by  $\phi(p(x))$=($p(x)$ mod $(x-1)$,$p(x)$ mod $(x+1)$),where p(x) is a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$.
let $p(x)=(x-1)q_1(x)+r_1$ , $p(x)=(x+1)q_2(x)+r_2$.
so $\phi(p(x))$=($r_1$,$r_2$).
We need to show $r_1\equiv r_2$ mod 2 to show our map is well-defined.
We notice $r_1=p(1)$ and $r_2=p(-1)$.
If we assume A(x) = sum of terms in p(x) with odd power ;
B(x) = sum of terms of p(x) with even power(include constant).
We have A(-x) = -A(x) ; B(-x) = B(x).
p(1) = A(1) + B(1) ; p(-1) = A(-1) + B(-1) = -A(1) + B(1).
so $r_1-r_2 = p(1)-p(-1) = 2A(1)$$\Rightarrow$$r_1\equiv r_2$ mod 2.
map $\phi$ is well-defined.
Next you just need to check $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.
$ker\phi = \{ p(x)|(x-1)|p(x)$ and $(x+1)|p(x)\} = \{p(x)|(x^2-1)|p(x)\}=(x^2-1)$.
We have $R \cong \mathbb Z [x]/(x^2-1)$.

Comment: you're welcome :-)

Comment: just have a question, why r1,r2 are constants？

Comment: well,since by Euclidean algorithm,we will have deg(r1)<deg(x-1)=1,so deg(r1)=0,which means r1 is a constant.similar proof for r2.

Comment: Thanks so much, but we also need to show the map is onto?

Comment: Yes.To show this map is onto is contained in showing this map is a ring homomorphism. Try to prove it.(hint:ax+b for some a,b)